# WordPress PHP Warning: require (/home/cluster-sites/6/e/expertfaculty.org/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php): failed to open stream

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I have recently moved a domain from an old server to a new hosting package.

I moved over all the previous files and backed up the MySQL databases.The website is not loading, with the following error:

> expertfaculty.org [Mon Oct 15 11:11:39 2018] [error] [client
> 77.89.128.187:0] PHP Warning:  require(/home/cluster-sites/6/e/expertfaculty.org/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/cluster-sites/6/e/expertfaculty.org/public_html/wp-settings.php
> on line 187
>
> expertfaculty.org [Mon Oct 15 11:11:39 2018] [error] [client
> 77.89.128.187:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/cluster-sites/6/e/expertfaculty.org/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php'
> (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear72:/usr/share/php') in
> /home/cluster-sites/6/e/expertfaculty.org/public_html/wp-settings.php
> on line 187

The class-wp-widget.php is there in the wp-includes file.
One wp-settings.php on line 187 there isn't anything that's relevant.

The website definitely worked under the old server. Not sure what is wrong.

Anyone can help on that? Thanks!

Comment: Seems line PHP configuration issue. Did you consult your hosting provider?

Comment: which is your root path?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the new site file: **wp-config.php**

Add the below above: **/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */**

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

Change the example.com URLs to your new site URLs.

Thanks.